# How to avoid gallstones?

Tags: gallstone

Maybe this is not the correct place to ask, but the answer I am seeking is from someone who has had gallstones, and they made changes to their diet, medicine, lifestlye (or whatever) to avoid them, and those changes worked.

I know it's possible to search Google, but I'd like to hear from people who've had the experience because I find such anecdotes very useful to consider. Again, this type of question may not be appropriate here. If not, please let me know and I'll happily get rid of it. Advice on how to improve the question to fit the site standards is very welcome, thanks!